# EF Code First hosting

Tags: asp.net, ef-code-first, hosting

What's my options (and where) for hosting a asp.net 4.5 on a hosting service?

I want to use the built-in membership tables + to be able to create automatically a new

database using EF Code First 5

- I want easy deploy
- Is it good option for Code First in production? I read a lot "Development only", but it's

bother me , why to have Code First if its only for development...

Update :

My main question is even about asp.net 3/4 Code-First , what known hosting services allow you easy deploy with the enjoy of CodeFirst , meaning , auto create database and etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well, your options are at the moment very limited. Firstly, as far as I know, 4.5 hasn't been released yet, so I'm not sure what hosting solutions are you actually expecting. I've heard of some testing hostings for beta version, but.. Don't know about you, but it just won't suffice for my production apps.

Secondly, code-first is meant for rapid development.

You must understand, that "code-first" is just a different way of creating your db classes in .NET. It's still Entity Framework, so if it suits you, it doesn't matter when and how you use it. Background layer is still the same as if you used "classical" auto-generated classes representing your db.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply , I used a free-beta 4.5 asp hosting with SQL 2008 , but I was limited on with CodeFirst because of permission which doesn't allow for creating a new database ( "create TABLE on master denied..."

Comment: @Zakos, I'd guess it wasn't a problem of version of the SQL server, but probably the restrictions on the server itself... Anyway, I'm not sure why you need a hosting with beta version. It's pretty much the same as if you were testing the app on your localhost server. Wouldn't really suggest to use beta versions for production use.

Answer (score 0):

It's only depend on .NET Framework 4.0.

It's very easy to deploy.